# Node Pug: Action attribute of form tag does not work properly when using variables

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have an index.pug page that is:

```html
    head
        title My Title
    body
        form(method="GET", action='/#{redirect_url}')
            button(type='submit') run foo
```

and in my app.js I have:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        redirect_url: '/foo'
    });
});

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Foo triggered');
});
```

I am being redirected to http://localhost:3000/?#{redirect_url}.

I want to get redirected to http://localhost:3000/redirect_url?

It works fine when I do not use variables.

I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
action=`${baseRoute}/${redirect_url}`
```